# Can Process.HasExited be true for the current process?

Tags: c#, .net

I have recently seen some production code to the effect of:

```
if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().HasExited)
{
    // do something
}
```

Does this make any sense? Intuitively, if the process has exited then no code can be running inside it.

If not, what would be a good way to tell if the current process is terminating?

If it can be of any relevance, the use case for this was to avoid popping assertions such as objects not disposed when the process is being killed.

Comment: it makes much sense to me, what's your problem?

Comment: As I said, "Intuitively, if the process has exited then no code can be running inside it.", therefore this code will not ever run and is pointless.

Comment: In What context the code is run? I mean multi-threading here.

Comment: It's a good question. If the process exited, is there still a place somwhere in the memory where the data is stored?

Comment: Seems pointless to me "A value of true for HasExited indicates that the associated process has terminated, either normally or abnormally."

Comment: @KingKing This is a utility method that can be called from anywhere on any thread.

Comment: Depending on what you are coding specifically there are at times "shutdown" hooks, otherwise, I don't believe so because `Process.GetCurrentProcess` would be the process running. Would it not?

Comment: @Asik ah, got it. However the `HasExited` is just a property of a **Process**, it's useful in other cases than this special one which never happens, **it's just your code**.

Comment: Does the code within the block do anything special or hint to why the check would be needed? Sounds like it could be a strange approach to creating a system which only allows your application to run one instance (usually done with a Mutex).

Comment: can you post some information about the content of the block, I would love to see what could happen in such a case in the opinion of the original developer

Comment: @eFloh Added a description of the use case.

Comment: “Popping assertions”? “Objects not being disposed when the process is being killed”? That doesn’t make sense… take the whole thing out.

Comment: @minitech Some objects have finalizers just to pop assertions if they ever run, i.e. they verify that the objects were disposed properly. But when a process is killed then it's *normal* that they are not disposed properly, and we don't want a bunch of asserts popping because of that.

Comment: @Asik If you use `Winforms` or `WPF`, we always have way to know if the process is being terminated, for example, in `winforms` we have `Application.ThreadExit`, ... isn't it enough?

Comment: @Asik it might be just a wording thing, but if a process is _killed_ (in the sense of `TerminateProcess` Win32 API or even `Process.Kill`) the process has no chance of popping up anything. It is destroyed by the OS without even knowing.

Comment: @Asik: That’s pointless. Plus, using a finalizer without needing one makes more work for the garbage collector, and the state of other objects during finalization apart from the one currently being destroyed is not necessarily what you hope it is. That’s so unnecessary it’s harmful.

Comment: Christian.K: I mean killing it from Task Manager, and yes it does pop asserts as finalizers run. I see it happening.

minitech: I disagree with your conclusions but I don't think it would be useful to pursue this discussion in this manner as it's ultimately irrelevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the source code of `IsExited` it turns out that nothing spectacular is happening. `IsExited` asks the OS whether the process has terminated and what the exit code was. That's it.

The whole topic of output redirection does not apply.

The code that you found there will always evaluate to false. Remove it and find out who wrote it to ask what he meant. Probably a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Thread.IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx):

> Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

For me, this means that no thread will ever execute any code once the process has been terminated.

As for the statement from [Process.HasExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx):

> When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have completed when this property returns true. To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter before checking HasExited.

I don't think this applies, because the async event handlers are threads in the current process and they will be terminated if the process itself has to terminate. They may only execute if they are attached to some other process.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you seem to be able to construct such a scenario:

see the note in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx:

> When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have completed when this property returns true. To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter before checking HasExited.

Comment: That’s output processing. The process still can’t run code when it’s not running.

Comment: That refers to *another* process, not your own.

Comment: good point. I'm curious what would happen if you catch your own output? But I must state that seems to be a dead end...

Comment: @eFloh: It’s not much different than redirecting any other process’s output.

Comment: @minitech: of course you are right, but could in that case be HasExited true? I suppose no, because that very process is still executing...